# Rename value if it is duplicate in json -

Tags: javascript, arrays

When there are multiple entries, I only want to append "_1","_2"....etc to json object, making sure no data is lost. If this is input:

```
 names_array = [
    {name: "a",  age: 15},
    {name: "a",  age: 16},
    {name: "a",  age: 17},
    {name: "b",  age: 18}
    {name: "b",  age: 19}];
```

I want the output to be

```
names_array_new = [
     {name: "a",  age: 15},
    {name: "a_1",  age: 16},
    {name: "a_2",  age: 17},
    {name: "b",  age: 18}
    {name: "b_1",  age: 19}
];
```

I have searched for this but only found how to remove duplicates when entire objects are same or retain the last found value.

Comment: if your question is solved consider marking any of the solutions by clicking the grey check-mark in an answer that help you as answered so others can see what helped in this case.

Answer (score 0):

there are possibly better solutions, but i came up with such quick snippet. take it and make better.

```js
name_changer = (n) => {
  splitted = n.split("_");
  if(splitted.length > 1) {
    name = splitted[0];
    ord = parseInt(splitted[1]);
    return `${name}_${ord+1}`
  } return `${n}_${1}`
} 

stack = []

names_array = [
    {name: "a",  age: 15},
    {name: "a",  age: 16},
    {name: "a",  age: 17},
    {name: "b",  age: 18},
    {name: "b",  age: 19}
];

names_array.forEach(obj => {
   if (stack.indexOf(obj.name) > -1) {
     obj.name = name_changer(obj.name);
   } stack.push(obj.name);
   
})


console.log(names_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check the `index` and name of each `a` and `b` and then rename the value of that object keys with `count++` with increment of count on each loop.

Just FYI - This can be improved more so wait for other `solutions` to come as well and choose what suits you best but this is **simple** and **straight** to your *desired output*!

**Expected Output Demo:**

```js
var names_array = [{
    name: "a",
    age: 15
  },
  {
    name: "a",
    age: 16
  },
  {
    name: "a",
    age: 17
  },
  {
    name: "b",
    age: 18
  }, {
    name: "b",
    age: 19
  }
];

var countA = 1 //count increase for a
var countB = 1 //count increase for b
names_array.forEach(function(obj, index) {
  if (obj.name == 'a' && index >= 1) {
    obj.name = obj.name + '_' + countA++; //rename a
  }
  if (obj.name == 'b' && index >= 4) {
    obj.name = obj.name + '_' + countB++; //rename b
  }
});


console.log(names_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `Array.prototype.reduce` to generate the desired output.

The handler basically keeps the previous processed values in order to save the current count and finally we get the result from the accumulator.

```js
let arr = [    {name: "a",  age: 15},    {name: "a",  age: 16},   {name: "a",  age: 17},    {name: "b",  age: 18},    {name: "b",  age: 19}],
    {result} = arr.reduce((a, {name: n, age}) => {
      let key = a.counts[n] = (a.counts[n] || a.counts[n] === "" ? (+a.counts[n] + 1) : ""),
          name = `${n}${key === "" ? "" : "_"}${key}`;
          
      a.result.push({name, age});
      return a;
    }, {counts: {}, result: []});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lookup object with key-value pairs of name value and its occurence

```js
const nameValueLookup = {}
const namesArray = [
  { name: "a", age: 15 },
  { name: "a", age: 16 },
  { name: "a", age: 17 },
  { name: "b", age: 18 },
  { name: "b", age: 19 },
]

const res = namesArray.map((obj) => {
  if (nameValueLookup[obj.name]) {
    return { ...obj, name: `${obj.name}_${nameValueLookup[obj.name]++}` }
  } else {
    nameValueLookup[obj.name] = 1
    return obj
  }
})

console.log(res)
```